# Standing wave in a string clamped at one end

Tags: waves, string, boundary-conditions, harmonics

*In the case of a standing wave formed with one end clamped (fixed), there is an anti-node at the free end irrespective of the overtone.

My question is why is there has to be an antinode. Is there any intuition behind it?

Comment: The image you've uploaded appears to be entirely black. In any case, we often prefer that you enter your formulas with LaTeX instead of attaching an image

Comment: @DanDan0101 I am not able to use that so I just removed the image and associated text. thanks for informing me.

Answer (score 4):

At the free end, the restoring force is zero (since it's free). This means the slope of the string at the end must be zero.

Why? The restoring force comes from the vertical component of tension, and tension is tangent to the string always. So if the restoring force is zero, the slope must be zero.

Only anti-nodes have the property of zero slope (max. deflection).